# Problem displaying content added from parent window to child window in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

Here is the code I am using to create and add content to a new window via JavaScript:

```
        var newWindow = window.open();
    newWindow.document.title = "This is my new window";
    newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<center>This is content added from the parent window</center>";
```

This works in every browser I have tested except Firefox. When I open firebug it shows the html added from the parent but it is not displaying it on the page?
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `newWindow.document.write()` instead of `newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = ""`.